# Sufficient conditions for a divisor to be connected on a K3 surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a K3 surface and $D$ an effective divisor such that $h^0(D)\geq2$ and $h^1(D)=0$.

Is this enough to show that $D$ is connected?

Any reference would also be appreciated (I looked in Saint-Donat' thesis but did not get the answer)

Comment: (Sorry; I originally misread the question, and left an incorrect comment.) Serre duality shows $h^1(D)=h^1(-D)$, and then the ideal sheaf sequence for $D$ shows that $h^0(O_D)=1$.

Comment: Pardon me @ArtiePrendergast-Smith but I am a bit 'slow'. So does $h^0(O_D)=1$ imply that $D$ is connected?

Comment: Yes, if there were $n$ connected components then $h^0(O_D) = n$ (each component gets its own vector space of constant global sections).

Comment: By the way, I think this question really belongs on M.SE.

Comment: Artie, why don't you write your comment as a proper answer (instead suggesting to relocate this question to M.SE), so that everyone can understand that your first comment is actually a complete answer :) ?

Comment: @aglearner: because I think the question should be on M.SE, and I am a stubborn old mule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is yes. Here is a sketch proof.

Keep in mind that by Serre duality that $h^2(D)=0$.

Suppose that the divisor is not connected. Then there are two possibilities:

1) There is an isolated exceptional subdivsor in $D$ (by this I mean a divisor $E$ that is a connected collection of $-2$ curves with $E^2<0$). It is clear that if you remove this divisor from $D$ then $h^0(D)$ will not change. At the same time $D^2$ will increase. From Riemann Roch it would follow that $\chi (D)$ increase as well. But since $h^0$ and $h^2$
don't change, this means that $h^1$ decreased. Hence it could not be zero in the beginning.

2) $D$ is a union of $\ge 2$ fibres of an elliptic fibration. In this case $\chi(D)=2$,
at the same time if $D$ is not connected then $h^0(D)\ge 3$. This gives by Riemann-Roch that $h^1(D)\ge 1$.

Comment: In fact after I wrote this answer I realised that the first comment of Artie solves the problem.